# How do I attach a weatherproof socket to a homemade outdoor light?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

Wondering what the best way is to attach a weatherproof bulb socket to the metal strap sphere seen below. It should also support a lightweight bulb cover on the socket or bulb.

One challenge is there's no threaded part on the socket and rubber isn't the easiest to permanently bond to and of course can't be welded to.

This will contain a 12V DC (not 120V AC) low voltage bulb.

Socket:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Weatherproof-Socket-Black-R60-00055-000/100356874

Sphere:
[image]

Comment: Those wires do hold some weight by themselves.  A light bulb and a light weight cover should not rip the wires out, so mounting/attaching to the sphere should not be needed.  I imagine there is a hole for the wires at the top.

Comment: @crip659 There's not a hole but there's a small round plate I can drill through easily enough. Good to know about the holding ability of the wires - should I use cable glands or something in conjunction?

Comment: I would like protection of the wires from sharp metal edges.

Comment: If you're going to dangle the socket by the wires, be sure to use a strain relief knot on the inside. Also, I support adding a cable gland to protect the wires from the metal edges. Outdoors = wind. Wind = movement. Movement = cutting insulation.

Answer (score 1):

Drill a hole in the metal and insert the socket. An interference fit sounds inadequate, so you'll want an adhesive. There's a good chance that any "weatherproof" rubber is EPDM, so be careful about choosing a compatible adhesive. I've seen a 3M gasket adhesive, for instance, that is not compatible with EPDM rubber. Super glue (cyanoacrylate) based products don't do well outdoors in humidity, so I would scratch that off the list of candidates. 3M has a weatherstripping adhesive called 08008 that sounds promising. They've got another product called 4799, but it sounds bad for the health and relatively expensive (unless you can find 0.1 ounces for sale somewhere).

Or you might find a weatherproof light socket with affordance for mechanical fastening.

Comment: Unfortunately, the plate up top is too small to fit the whole socket - any other thoughts on how best to approach? Thanks for the note on EPDM.

Comment: @g491, weld on a bigger plate or bolt on a bigger plate. Shape a ribbon of steel into a teardrop shape. Bolt that onto one of the exterior ribbons and drill it for mounting the light.

Comment: Those type of sockets are made to hang down by the wires.  Usually in low head spaces where your head could smash the bulb if it was solidly affixed to a standard light socket.

Comment: Get a small angle bracket, screw/bolt it to one of the metal "straps" so that one end of the angle is vertical, use a hose clamp to clamp the socket to the bracket.  (Trim the angle bracket short if necessary.)  Use stainless wherever you can.